# Access Users from Group model Django

Tags: django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to access the users inside the group model of django.

For now i can only access it the other way, the groups from the user model.

I want to be able to do multiple action from the Group endpoints:

- Retreive the users inside the group and return them inside the view
- create a group and add user directly in the request
- update the group to add or remove a user from it

I've done the same thing for the permissions, i can add them inside the groupe, but i can't do it for the user because there isn't a field for the users inside the group model.

To do it for the permission i made a serializer

I would like to do the same as the Permissions field, but for the users, is there any way ?
I looked to override the Group model and add a field so a could use it in the serializer but i didn't find how to do so.

```py
    class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        Id = serializers.IntegerField(source='id', required=False)
        Name = serializers.CharField(source='name')
        Permissions = PermissionSerializer(source='permissions', many=True, required=True)
        class Meta:
            model = Group
            fields = ('Id','Name','Permissions',)
        def create(self, validated_data):
            print(validated_data)
            permissions_data = validated_data.pop('permissions')
            permissions = []
            for permission in permissions_data:
                permissions.append(get_object_or_404(Permission.objects.all(), pk=permission['id']))
    
            group = Group.objects.create(**validated_data)
            group.permissions.set(permissions)
    
            return group
    
        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
           
            instance.name = validated_data.get('name', instance.name)
           
            
            if validated_data.get('permissions'):
                permissions_data = validated_data.pop('permissions')
                permissions = []
                for permission in permissions_data:
                    permissions.append(get_object_or_404(Permission.objects.all(), pk=permission['id']))
                instance.permissions.set(permissions)
    
            instance.save()
    
            return instance
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get an user's group by doing a reverse foreign key lookup:

```
request.user.groups.all()
# or if you want to see other User's groups
User.objects.get(<your filter here>).groups.all()
```

Notice the `.all()` at the end: that's because user.groups returns a QuerySet Manager.

Comment: This line is only for connected user right ? Or i can use is in the view for a user that's not connected but on thats updated by an admin ? What i want to do is for the administrators, they can manages the users and add or remove the selected user from groups.

Comment: What do you mean connected? Registered or Logged in?

Comment: I mean the user thats is doing the request, for exemple admin1 want to update user1. Then admin1 will do a request to update the groups of user1, and in that case request.user will be admin1 and not user1 ?